# php to unity how to pass byte[] or binary data?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

i am working on a C# unity project. 
i have some objects which i would like to save on the php server.

so first i serialize them to json, then compress them and upload them to the server, 
which saves it on the db (as binary, is string good enough?).

now i want to fetch back that data on unity. how should the php return the value? and how should the unity receive it?

i will handle decompressing, and deserializing to json. (using jsonfx for json and using compress method written in c# natively)
this part works fine.

i only need to be able to receive the same byte[] on each platform.

it should look something like this

C# - to upload the data (psuedo C#) //this part works well

```
wwwform myform= new wwwform ()
byte[] mybytearr = ...
wwwform.addbinary ($mybytearr);
WWW myw=    new www (url,myform)
```

C# - to fetch the data (need help here)

```
WWW www = > new www (url,formdata)
myinput =www.text;
```

PHP - to send the data back the to client (and need help here)
...

```
$myvarbackfromthedb =.
echo $myoutput
```

how do i do the same when $myoutput is a binary data or byte[]?

Thanks for your help!

update:

so the motivation for this was to save the byte[] that the compress returned. i ended up, moving it to base64 string, and then pass it as string to the php and then as string to the database.

Comment: Maybe help yoou json_decode()?

Comment: no, the im ok the json part, just need to recive the byte[] in unity after that im ok.

Comment: Can you show bit of your binary string?

Comment: straight out of the editor {"buildings":[{"core_id":{"GameEngineName":"basic-launcher-2.0",�%Typ@%DefenseB�V "scenenam@B1"},"`eloc@fx":17,"y":1,"z":0}�radar":null,"hp":100},{�Y�2"}����-2,��-34}�!�p�3"����12��8}�w�4"����

Comment: @tansgrs -> ok, but how do i put it back to client just echo "$myvarin64base"? and then just read www.text on c# unity client side?

Comment: No this is not base64 encoded. This JSON encoded string, and here is trouble with charset. You can try to get data, like this
`$str = 'here your enceoded string';
$str = iconv('from what charset', 'to what charset', $str);
print_r(json_decode($str, true));`

Comment: thanks, i dont want the php to return the giant json string, i want it to return the same bytearr[] it sent to begin with.

Comment: How are you creating that JSON string?

Comment: The Unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with some binary data:

```
$binary = file_get_contents('/tmp/foo');
```

Or maybe for testing purposes:

```
$binary = join(array_map('chr', range(0, 127)));
```

Both are some arbitrary binary strings. You can output a valid JSON string from them using:

```
echo json_encode(array('foo' => $binary));
```

This will give you something like this:

```
{"foo":"\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f !\"#$%&'()*+,-.\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"}
```

That's a valid JSON representation of that binary data. Anybody who is *decoding* that data will get the binary value back. You may want to encode it a little more efficiently though, for example using Base 64 encoding:

```
echo json_encode(array('foo' => base64_encode($binary)));
```

This'll give you:

```
{"foo":"AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0+P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXV5fYGFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn8="}
```

Now the receiver just has to decode it again. In PHP that'd look like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data['foo'] = base64_decode($data['foo']);
```

Comment: thanks i will check it, might take a while. to make sure u suggest to "wrap" the binari data as json on its way back to the c# client, correct?

Comment: How exactly you do it depends on you. You can send the binary data *as part of a JSON* response, or you can send the data directly in binary without surrounding extra data, you can use a multi-part HTTP response... there are so many ways to do it, it depends on what's best for your situation and what's easiest to consume for your client. What I showed is how to send it as JSON, which is one simple way to do it.

Comment: how will the reciver recive that $data['foo']? will the php echo $data, and c# get it as text and proceed from there?